# How do I get my area map links to work correctly?

Tags: html, image, dictionary, area

I'm trying to create an area map to make email addresses inside a full screen picture clickable, the reason for this is that the design has been provided by another designer and the client has asked that I don't recreate all of the divs in HTML (not that I would want to).

I've used https://www.image-map.net/ to generate the co-ordinates for the area map, here is my jsfiddle that I am using to test before I add it to my webpage:

https://jsfiddle.net/vanstone/xL86wkfv/6/

**HTML:**

```
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/3rLpPtjB/Email-Panel-Example.png" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="_blank" alt="Email 1" title="Email 1" href="mailto:e1@email.com" coords="581,722,793,745" shape="rect">
    <area target="_blank" alt="Email 2" title="Email 2" href="mailto:e2@email.com" coords="859,721,1006,743" shape="rect">
    <area target="_blank" alt="Email 3" title="Email 3" href="mailto:e3@email.com" coords="583,891,782,914" shape="rect">
</map>
```

I was expecting the area map to at least show up somewhere on the image but I can't locate any clickable links anywhere on the image. Any ideas on what is going wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your `map` coordinates are outside of the `img` dimension. The coords on your areas start at high numbers, but the `img` is much smaller.

When doing map areas like that, you should specify exactly the dimension of your `img`. I have shown a possible solution using your `img` below:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 1280px;
  height: 720px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/3rLpPtjB/Email-Panel-Example.png" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="mailto:censored1@example.com" coords="211,192,50,47" shape="rect">
    <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="mailto:censored2@example.com" coords="806,267,674,139" shape="rect">
    <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="mailto:censored3@example.com" coords="118,461,258,592" shape="rect">
</map>
```